# Voltage Drop Across Wire With Fixed Load Wattage

Tags: math, algorithm

I am looking for an equation to calculate DC voltage drop across wires that run a distance, with a switching regulator and fixed load at the end (a known wattage).

Here are the specifics:

The power source is 19.5v (going into the length of wire).

The regulator is at the end of the wire, with an estimated 95% efficiency.

The regulator output voltage is 5v, and there will be a 0.8A load. 5V * 0.8A = 4W, and at 95% efficiency that is a load of about 4.2 watts (4W / 0.95 = about 4.2W) being drawn through and used by the regulator.

The total wire resistance is estimated to be 10.18 ohms (23 gauge, 250 feet each way, or 500 feet total).

And that is as far as I have gotten. I'm looking for an equation to calculate the voltage drop across the wire, given the above values.

At first I thought I could just make the following calculations: 4.2W / 19.5V = about 0.22A, then 10.18 ohms * 0.22A = about 2.24V, then 19.5V - 2.24V = 17.26V at the regulator's input. However, that fails to account for the power being "wasted" as heat, due to the wire's resistance. I would take that 0.22A * 2.24V and assume the wire uses about 0.5W, but due to the voltage drop of the wire, the current is actually higher in order for the regulator to still pull 4.2W.

So, how can I calculate the voltage drop, knowing the source voltage (19.5V), the wire resistance (10.18ohms), and the load wattage (4.2W)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The power delivered by the supply will be 19.5V*I. The power wasted in the wire will be I^2/R, and the power delivered to the load will be 4.2W. Putting this all together you get:

$$19.5 V \cdot I-I^2 \cdot 10.2\Omega = 4.2W$$

This is a quadratic equation in \$I\$, which can be solved to get \$I=247.4mA\$ or \$I=1.664A\$. The higher current solution corresponds to the condition where all the voltage is dropped in the cable, so the lower current one is the correct answer. This gives a voltage drop in the cable of \$247.4mA\cdot10.2\Omega=2.523V\$, and an input voltage of \$16.98V\$ at the load.

Answer (score 0):

@Austin thank you very much. That seems to line up with this graph I created (sorry for the poor Y axis scale).

Y axis is voltage, X axis is amperage. The red line indicates the voltage at the end of the wires (based on the amperage), and the blue indicates the voltage and current required to provide 4.2W. They do indeed appear to cross at 247.4mA and 1.664A.

[image]

And here is a simple python program to do all of the calculations:

```
import sys, math

SOURCE_VOLTAGE = 19.5   # The voltage to start with

WIRE_RESISTANCE = 10.18   # Remember that it's there and back again (+v and -v lines)

REGULATED_VOLTAGE = 5.0   # or STARTING_VOLTAGE if there is not a regulator
REGULATED_CURRENT = 0.8   # The amperage required from the regulator
REGULATOR_EFFICIENCY = 0.95 # Regulator efficiency, for a switching regulator

NEEDED_WATTS = (REGULATED_VOLTAGE * REGULATED_CURRENT) / REGULATOR_EFFICIENCY

print "Source Voltage: %.2f" % SOURCE_VOLTAGE
print "Wire Resistance: %.2f" % WIRE_RESISTANCE
print "Needed Watts: %.2f" % NEEDED_WATTS

d = SOURCE_VOLTAGE * SOURCE_VOLTAGE - 4 * WIRE_RESISTANCE * NEEDED_WATTS

if d < 0:
    print "Impossible with the provided parameters.\n"
    sys.exit()

SOURCE_CURRENT = -(( -SOURCE_VOLTAGE + math.sqrt(d)) / (2* WIRE_RESISTANCE))
print "Source Current: %.2f" % SOURCE_CURRENT

VOLTAGE_DROP = SOURCE_CURRENT * WIRE_RESISTANCE
print "Voltage Drop: %.2f" % VOLTAGE_DROP

print "Watts wasted: %.4f" % (VOLTAGE_DROP * SOURCE_CURRENT)
print "Total Watts used: %.4f" % ((VOLTAGE_DROP * SOURCE_CURRENT) + NEEDED_WATTS)

ENDING_VOLTAGE = (SOURCE_VOLTAGE - VOLTAGE_DROP)
print "Final Voltage: %.2f" % ENDING_VOLTAGE

sys.exit()
```